# Creating Controllers in MVC 5 using the Models present in a Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class-library

I have a bit of a problem. I have created all my models in a different Class Library. Now, I have to create a controller in a MVC Web Application using the models present in the Class Library. I am not able to see the Models that I created in the Class Library while creating a controller in MVC. How do I proceed on getting all the models in Class Library to the MVC project. I have even added a reference of the Class Library to the MVC project.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using DomainClasses; 

namespace TestingModel.Controllers 
{ 
    public class ProductsGroupController : Controller 
    { // 
        // GET: /ProductsGroup/ 
        public ActionResult Index() 
        { 
            return View(); 
        } 
    } 
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;

namespace DomainClasses.Models
{
    public class ProductGroupMaster
    {
        public int ProductGroupID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined a `using YourClassDll` in your controller?

Comment: Yes I did @mehdi lotfi

Comment: Are they defined as public? Can you share some sample code?

Comment: Yes they are defined as public. All I want is to create a Controller using the Models that I created in the ClassLibrary.

Comment: There is no magic behind it. If you have added the reference as you said, and defined the using then you should be able to use them. Maybe there is something on your code? Pls post a sample of your external class code, and your controller.

Comment: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DomainClasses;

namespace TestingModel.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsGroupController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ProductsGroup/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
 }
}'

Comment: Ok, i was about to ask you to post a sample of the DomainClasses. I would also like to see how have you tried to access it. Are you sure that `DomainClasses.Models.ProductGroupMaster` is not accessible?

Comment: I tried to create a **MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework**. but DomainClasses.Models.ProductMaster was not listed in the **Model Class select List**.